# How to display the image of second uploader of carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, upload, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave to upload the imgae, i have used in one model, now i want to use carrierwave to upload images in other model within same app,

i have create uploader as,

```
$ rails g uploader image2
$ rails g migration add_image_to_products image2:string
```

in model

```
attr_accessible :gallery_id, :name, :image2
mount_uploader :image2, ImageUploader
```

it uploads the file i have check in the folder, but not able to display the image,

```
image_tag product.image_url.to_s
```

Got this error

```
undefined method `image_url' for #<Product:0x49a3e68>
```

**Note:** In the same app i have used the Carrierwave and able to display the image as wel for that model which is Category, but have problem with Product model, i am trying to using carrierwave to upload files for Product model..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't it be

**image_tag product.image2_url.to_s**?

beacause you are using the uploader called **image2**!

Comment: Thats great... Thank you ssoooooooooooooooooo much... :)
i was trying image2_tag product.image2_url.to_s